# Combinations of words

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

3. How many ways can the letters of the word MISSISSIPPI be arranged if the letters must begin and end with P?

Comment: you just fix the two P's and arrange the remaining letters arbitrarily.

Comment: @inquisitive: The word MISSISSII only has $$\frac{9!}{4!^2}=630$$ anagrams, not $9!$.

Comment: Do you have to use all the letters? Are we considering each letter as being unique? (ie, if we had $'MIS_1S_2'$ would $'S_1IS_2M'$ be the same as $'S_2IS_1M'$ or are they considered different permutations?)

Comment: Yes we have to use each letter even the repeated

Comment: Since there are only 2 'P' letters, and they must appear in beg. and end, you can ignore them all together and focus on the permutations of the other 7 letters. Now for the other seven you need to consider duplicate letters. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15884/permutation-with-duplicates

Comment: Repeated question answered (here)[http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681998/how-many-ways-are-there-to-arrange-the-letters-in-the-word-mississippi-such-th?rq=1]

Answer (score 1):

We stick the P's on the outside $$P\overbrace{MISSISSII}P$$ and count the number of ways of arranging the internal letters.  So the problem has the same answer as:

> How many ways can the letters of the word MISSISSII be arranged?

Generally, this can be solved using the multinomial coefficient.  But in this case, we can:

- start with 9 empty slots (to fill with one M, four S's, and four I's),
- choose 1 slot to put in an M,
- choose 4 of the remaining slots to put in S's, and
- put I's in the remaining slots.